# how make a row with 3 elements and show 2 in mobile view Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I need show 9 elements(div) in rows of 3, but that row show only 2 elements on mobile view, how i make this?

```
| elem_0 | elem_1 | elem_2 |   <--- on desktop
| elem_3 | elem_4 | elem_5 |

| elem_0 | elem_1 |
| elem_2 | elem_3 |     <--- on mobile view
| elem_4 | elem_5 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this use multiple `col-*-*` classes targeting both larger screen sizes such as `md` and `lg` then `sm` and `xs` at smaller screen sizes. At the larger screen sizes you'll target `col-*-4` (1/3) and at smaller screen sizes you'll target `col-*-6` (1/2). If given Bootstrap `row` ends up have `col-*-*` totaling more than `12`, they will overflow into the next visible row:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">0</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">1</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">2</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">3</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Example:

http://www.bootply.com/SSuDcf7RSh

You may need to adjust the `col-sm-6` on each `<div>` element to suit your breakpoint needs. Not sure what `px` screen width you are considering mobile.